# How to prove $\int f d\mu=\sup_{n\geq 1}\int f d\mu_n$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Suppose we have a measurable space $(X, A)$, $\{\mu_n\}_{n\geq1}$ is a sequence of increasing measures on it. (i.e. $\mu_n(E) \leq \mu_{n+1}(E), \forall E \in A$).

First prove $\mu(A)= \sup(\mu_n(A))$ is a measure.

Then prove for non-negative measurable function $f$, we have,

$$\int f d\mu=\sup_{n\geq 1}\int f d\mu_n$$.

My try and questions:

1. Prove $\mu$ is sigma additive. $\mu(\cup E_i)=\sup_{n} \mu_n(\cup E_i)= \lim _n\mu_n(\cup E_i)= \lim_{n} \sum \mu_n(E_i)$, then how can we change the limits and summation?
2. For simple functions, I can easily check $\int f d\mu=\sup_{n\geq 1}\int f d\mu_n$, however when dealing with non-negative functions, I met problems. Suppose $f_m$ is the sequence of simple functions that converge to $f$, so we have  $\int f d\mu= \lim_{m}\int f_m d\mu = \lim_{m} \sup_{n\geq 1}\int f_m d\mu_n$, If I can change supremum and limits, I will get the answer. But I can not make it clear.

Comment: For (1), apply the monotone convergence theorem for series (i.e., MCT for counting measure). Alternatively, use the fact that suprema can be always interchanged: for any non-empty sets $A, B$ and for any function $f:A\times B\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$, we have $$\sup_{a\in A}\sup_{b\in B}f(a,b)=\sup_{(a,b)\in A\times B}f(a, b)=\sup_{b\in B}\sup_{a\in A}f(a, b).$$ In (1), you may consider $f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to[0,\infty]$ given by $f(n,m)=\sum_{i=1}^{m}\mu_n(E_i)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(2) Notice that $\mu_n\leq \mu$ for all $n$ and so, $\int f\,d\mu_n\leq \int f\,d\mu$ for all $n$ and all  measurable $f\geq0$. Equality holds for all simple functions (by definition of $\mu$).

Suppose $f\geq0$ is measurable. Let $f_m$ a sequence of simple nonnegative functions such that $f_m\nearrow f$.

Notice that if $\sup_n\int f\,d\mu_n<\infty$, then
$$\int f_m\,d\mu=\sup_n \int f_m\,d\mu_n\leq\sup_n\int f\,d\mu_n<\infty$$
Hence
$$\int f\,d\mu=\lim_m\int f_m\,d\mu\leq \sup_n\int f\,d\mu_n<\infty.$$
This also shows that $\int f\,d\mu=\sup_n\int f\,d\mu_n$.

---

(1) I leave the details to the OP (details to work out are marked by *why?*).

Notice that

- $\mu(\emptyset)=0$ (why?).
- if $A,B$ are measurable and $A\subset B$, $\mu(A)\leq \mu(B)$, for $\mu_n(A)\leq \mu_n(B)$ for all $n$ (why?).
- If $A$ and $B$ are measurable and disjoint, $\mu(A\cup B)=\mu(A)+\mu(B)$ (why?).

Let $(A_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ be a sequence of pairwise disjoint measurable functions whose union is $A$. Then
$$\mu(A)\geq\mu\Big(\bigcup^n_{j=1}A_j\Big)=\sum^n_{j=1}\mu(A_j)$$
Hence $\mu(A)\geq\sum^\infty_{n=0}\mu(A_n)$.
Now, if $c<\mu(A)$, then there is $N$ such that $c<\mu_N(A)$ (why?). It follows that
$$c<\mu_N(A)=\sum_k\mu_N(A_k)\leq\sum_k\mu(A_k)$$
As this holds for all $c<\mu(A)$, we can conclude that
$$\mu(A)=\sum_k\mu(A_k)$$

Comment: Very nice answers! But I do not get the last two lines, why if we have $\forall c$ if $c < \mu (A)$, then $c \leq \sum \mu(A_n)$, we can conclude $\mu(A) \leq \sum \mu(A_n)$.

Comment: Notice that $c<\sum_k\mu(A_k)$ for all numbers $c<\mu(A)$. Letting $c\nearrow \mu(A)$ yields $\mu(A)\leq\sum_k\mu(A_k)$. We have already seen that $\sum_k\mu(A_k)\leq \mu(A)$...